# How to handle real numbers in a neural network?

Tags: neural-network

I've been playing with neural networks. I started with approximating a XOR function without too many problems. But, then I attacked the problem of approximating the sqrt function.

The problem is that the input as well as the output can be any real numbers, not only numbers in ]0,1[

Is there a way I can handle that in the neural network so that it can output real numbers directly ?

Or do I have to normalize the input and output data to be in the ]0,1[ range ? Isn't that a loss of precision ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found that the most reasonable and generic solution was to normalize the inputs and then denormalize the outputs.

The user has to set the input / output ranges and then everything works well.

This is what is done by most of the neural networks frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

You can choose another activation function in your output layer, e.g. g(a) = a (identity). However, you should have a hidden layer with a nonlinear activation function (tanh, logistic) to approximate nonlinear functions.

Comment: I just tried now. If I use a tanh or a sigmoid as the activation function of the hidden layer and then an identity activate function in the output layer, I have some problems with the weights that are becoming Infinity... It is probably a problem with my backpropagation algorithm.

Comment: That is the only reason that I can think of for such an easy problem. Maybe it helps to see a correct implementation, e.g. https://github.com/AlexanderFabisch/OpenANN/blob/master/src/FullyConnected.cpp (functions: forwardPropagate and backpropagate; with matrix operations)